# Incorrect order execution on my server TCP (node.js)

Tags: node.js

I attached my server code:

```
var net = require('net');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('MyBBDD.db');
var prueba = '';

function get_kw_actual(nombre,callback){ 
    stmt = db.prepare("SELECT kw_actual FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?");
        stmt.bind(nombre);
        stmt.get(function(error,row){
            if(error){
                throw err;
            }
            else{
                if(row){
                    entero=row.kw_actual;
                    callback(entero);
                }
                else{
                    console.log("error");
                }
            }
        }); 
}

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    console.log("Recibo peticion");

    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        get_kw_actual('Pepe',function(resultado){
            console.log('resultado es: ' + resultado);
            prueba = '' + resultado;
        })
        socket.write(prueba);
    });

    socket.on('close', function () {
            console.log('Connection closed');
    });

});
server.listen(1337, '192.168.1.101');
```

In my server, I receive a request, I call to my function "get_kw_actual" I get a number of my database and finally I respond with the result.
The problem is that it runs first "socket.write(prueba);" than:

```
stmt.get(function(error,row){
            if(error){
                throw err;
            }
            else{
                if(row){
                    entero=row.kw_actual;
                    callback(entero);
                }
                else{
                    console.log("error");
                }
            }
        });
```

So... the execution is not executed in the correct order and the result is not correct.
Somebody know how can I solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js code runs asynchronously. The code in the callback `get_kw_actual` returns immediately but the callback will run at some later time, when the database operation has completed. What you want to do is put `socket.write` inside of the callback, like this:

```
socket.on('data', function (data) {
    get_kw_actual('Pepe',function(resultado){
        console.log('resultado es: ' + resultado);
        socket.write(resultado);
    })
});
```

Also note that you're using a global variable `prueba` in your code, which will get clobbered when you have multiple clients running against your server. Do not use global variables like this in node.